# Spec Explorer for beginners

Tags: c#, .net, testing

where can I find a good tutorial for Spec Explorer (beginner) ?

Comment: You might be able to find an answer in their forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/specexplorer/threads

Comment: Questions seeking recommendation of off-site resources are considered to be off-topic here on Stack-Overflow.

Comment: In addition to that. Your question seems to be Primarily opinion based. There's not any fixed solution to your question. Which too is considered as a off-topic question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple links, the first being full of information, the second being more of what you're looking for:

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=77383

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee692301.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've created a tutorial for Spec Explorer using Visual Studio at http://rasmus.selsmark.dk/post/2013/09/16/Spec-Explorer-Tutorial-for-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx.

Covers Visual Studio 2012, but should work for Visual Studio 2010 as well.

Comment: Hum... This is useful introduction to Spec Explorer thanks, however I find this way of doing things suspicious. I have serious doubts they intended their tool to be that intrusive

Answer (score 0):

Spec Explorer is now [VS.NET Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/271d0904-f178-4ce9-956b-d9bfa4902745/)